# What is the error in my code when i trying to pass values as Get through Ajax to a php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I m trying to pass value through get as Ajax request but on the php page it shows indefined index. My code is 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/88qpmkwmaepa5s4/New%20Text%20Document%20%283%29.txt

Any help is appreciated

JS:

```
function showDiv(id) {
    loadXMLDoc(id); 
    document.getElementById('pop1').style.display = "block";  
}

function loadXMLDoc(id)
{       
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //returned response from ajax to the php page will be in xmlhttp.responseText
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // Do whatever you need with the respones
        }
    }
    var selected_row = id   
    window.alert(selected_row);
    xmlhttp.open("GET","view_details.php&row_id=" + encodeURIComponent(selected_row), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP:

```
    <table id="rounded-corner">             
<?php               
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mgen_cust_contacts where Cust_code='$j'");
    if($result==FALSE)
        die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

    <tr>                        
        <td><?php echo $row['cust_code'] ?></td>            
        <td><?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['last_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['designation'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['department'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['phone'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['mobile'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>            
        <td><a href='#pop1' onclick="showDiv(<?php echo $row['sr_no'] ?>)" class="classname">View</a></td>
        <td><?php echo "<a href='#pop2' class='classname'>Edit</a>" ?></td>         
        <td><?php echo "<a href='#pop3' class='classname'>Delete</a>" ?></td>
    </tr>           
    <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Please post your code here. Dropbox only has the Javascript, you need to post the PHP, too.

Comment: Window.alert is showing the right values. Any ways the link for php page is https://www.dropbox.com/s/lifv6z2ob1l9yvs/New%20Text%20Document%20%284%29.txt

Comment: You have to post your code HERE! Not as dropbox links.

Comment: I am not able to indent my code. That is why I m posting the code in dropbox. Clicking wont take much time. Help me if possible. :(

Comment: Why can't you indent your code? Paste it into the input box, mark it wiyth the mouse, and use the `{}` tool to render it as code.

Comment: thanks I started suing stackoverflow some days ago. Anyways thanks for teaching me this.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Your JS is sending `row_id`, but the PHP is looking for `customername`. It doesn't seem like these two scripts are related at all.

Comment: Also, it should be `view_details.php?row_id` -- the separator between the script name and parameters is `?`; `&` is used to separate different parameters.

Comment: Actually I m trying to access row_id in view_details.php.That is another page. It shows undefined index when i try to echo $_POST['row_id']. This customername is for this current page

Comment: Why in the world aren't you using jQuery or some other client side library that handles AJAX requests for you? There is no reason to "reinvent the wheel". Also, `console.log` is a lot better than using alert dialogues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `GET` method to invoke the script, you access the parameter using `$_GET['row_id']`, not `$_POST['row_id']`.

If you want your script to be invoked either with `GET` or `POST`, you can use `$_REQUEST['row_id']`. All the `GET` and `POST` parameters are merged into `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: I am using $_GET['row_id'] in view_details.php but still it shows undefined index.

Comment: Please post the real code that you want us to help you with. What was the point of that dropbox link with totally irrelevant code?